# Running js code from erlang

Tags: erlang

In order to run js code from Erlang I found this library https://github.com/strange/erlang_v8, it works great, but I cannot figure out how to add any js library to context, for example [marked](https://github.com/markedjs/marked). How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by downloading [marked.min.js](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/blob/master/marked.min.js) from marked sources and giving path to it in erlang_v8:start_vm/1 function like that:

```
> {ok, VM} = erlang_v8:start_vm([{file, "path-in-file-system/marked.min.js"}]).
```

Then I use it just as follow:

```
> {ok, Context1} = erlang_v8:create_context(VM).
{ok,242}
> erlang_v8:call(VM, Context1, <<"marked">>, [<<"# Marked in the browser\n\nRendered by **marked**.">>]).
{ok,<<"<h1 id=\"marked-in-the-browser\">Marked in the browser</h1>\n<p>Rendered by <strong>marked</strong>.</p>\n">>}
```